# Android NDK SHA1 or SHA256 functions

Tags: c++, android-ndk

Are there any built-in SHA1 or SHA256 functions available in the Android NDK?

I'm looking for something similar to [mhash.h](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mhash) on linux.

Comment: Option (1) use JNI to call the available Java security functions.  (2) use an external library for example OpenSSL.

Comment: Definitely not going to use JNI here for something performance critical. Using OpenSSL or libsodium works, but may not be as fast as something provided by the OS. I really just want to know if Google has a C++ implementation of this that's hardware accelerated.

Comment: They don't, the Android Source uses OpenSSL (you can see it in the build source tree).  But it's not callable from the NDK, you need to build and include your own copy of it.